# SQLiteDatabase Auto backup and restore

Tags: sqlite, backup, restore, back

How can backup and restore to firebase of my SQLite Database DATA

My DatabaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user_details.db";

    /* User Details Table */

    public static final String TABLE_NAME_1 = "user_details";
    public static final String COL_1_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2_1 = "PHONE_NUMBER";
    public static final String COL_3_1 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_4_1 = "PASSCODE";
    public static final String COL_5_1 = "BUSINESS_NAME";
    public static final String COL_6_1 = "LOCATION";
    public static final String COL_7_1 = "CREATED_TIME";
    public static final String COL_8_1 = "STATUS";      // 1] Personal 2] Add Contact 3] Delete
    public static final String COL_9_1 = "IMAGE";

    /* Transaction Table */

    ......

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_1 +" ("+COL_1_1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COL_2_1+" INTEGER,"+COL_3_1+" TEXT,"+COL_4_1+" TEXT,"+COL_5_1+" TEXT,"+COL_6_1+" TEXT,"+COL_7_1+" DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,"+COL_8_1+" INTEGER,"+COL_9_1+" blob)");
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_2 +" ("+COL_1_2+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COL_2_2+" INTEGER,"+COL_3_2+" INTEGER,"+COL_4_2+" INTEGER,"+COL_5_2+" INTEGER,"+COL_6_2+" TEXT,"+COL_7_2+" DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,"+COL_8_2+" TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_3 +" ("+COL_1_3+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COL_2_3+" INTEGER,"+COL_3_3+" INTEGER,"+COL_4_3+" DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME_1);
```

And my dashboard.java...